# Rolling database - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to come up with an archiving solution and would like to implement the following architecture:

1. `Main Table` - kept small.
2. `Copy Job` - takes a 3 month worth of data and copies the data into an archive table.
3. When the archive tables reaches certain number of record the job creates a new table thus the database keeps rolling accumulating approx a calendar year worth of records.

My questions are:

1. Are there any ready solutions I can refer to?
2. Common design practices to execute on?

Comment: Any reason you want multiple archive tables as opposed to just one?

Comment: The data is very sensitive (Medical Audit Logs) I'd like to keep the database rolling for easier back up. The roll will not delete anything. All the data to be kept in tact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, take a look at [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), especially the [Sliding-Window Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic24) portion of the article.